# Why x = y = z does not return false

Tags: basic

I have a piece of code that compares three values each defaulting to zero but it does not return false:

```
x = 0 : y = 0 : z = 0
IF x = y = z THEN PRINT "false"
```

and I cannot figure out why?

Comment: BASIC doesn’t have a fancy chained `=` like Python. You’re comparing `(x = y) = z`.

Comment: So, if (x = y) is -1, then (-1 = 0) is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older dialects of BASIC the following assigned all variables to zero:

```
a = b = c = 0
```

but after that each variable has to be set separately:

```
a = 0 : b = 0 : c = 0
```

then instead of comparing all values to zero, they were compared in boolean fashion between each: a=b=c would calculate a=b first then its value compared to c..

Comment: ¿What dialect of BASIC are you using?

Comment: ¿Um, old M$ products, such as: QB45, PDS71, VBdos Pro 1.0, and QB64 mostly.. Why?